# Python win32com PivotCache.CreatePivotTable() error: 'The parameter is incorrect'

Tags: python, excel, anaconda, pivot-table, win32com

The following code executes without error up until the PivotCache.CreatePivotTable() statement.  Excel or windows COM is having a problem with something.  The error message indicates that the problem is with the parameters passed but that does not appear to be a correct error message.

I can execute the same methods in VBA and works without error (syntax is a little different - but passing the same parameter values).

Do I need to type the parameters differently?

- The error is returned from win32com.
- There are ample code examples for this.
- Anaconda Python 3.6.
- Excel 2013.
- I have reinstalled win32com (conda install win32com).

#### Code

```
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') 
win32c = win32com.client.constants

####\#load the workbook
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open('c:\devworkspace\SQL-Pandas-Excel\LargeClaims.xlsx')

####\#create a worksheet object for source data
src_sheet = wb.Worksheets('Total Direct Pay')

####\#add the pivot table work sheet and name
pvt_sheet = wb.Sheets.Add(After=src_sheet)
pvt_sheet.Name = 'Pivot Sheet'

####\#set the source range  "Total Direct Pay!R2C2:R162855C19"
rng_row = int(largest_claims_df.shape[0])
rng_col = int(largest_claims_df.shape[1])
pvt_src = "%s!R2C2:R%dC%d"%(src_sheet.Name,rng_row+1,rng_col+1) \# offset index and header

####\#Create the Pivot Cache
pc = wb.PivotCaches().Add(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=pvt_src)

####\#Create the Pivot Table
try:
    pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination='Pivot Sheet!R4C1',TableName='PivotTable1')
except pythoncom.com_error as error:
    print(error.excepinfo[5])
    print(win32api.FormatMessage(error.excepinfo[5]))
```

Here is the error code and translated message:

```
-2147024809
The parameter is incorrect.
```

Also the complete stack trace not handled:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-6924c75f990d> in <module>()
      7 
      8 
----> 9 pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination='Pivot 
Sheet!R4C1',TableName='PivotTable1')
     10 
     11 
 
 C:\Users\BARTRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\00020813-0000-0000-C000- 000000000046x0x1x8\PivotCache.py in CreatePivotTable(self, TableDestination, TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)
     43         def CreatePivotTable(self, TableDestination=defaultNamedNotOptArg, TableName=defaultNamedOptArg, ReadData=defaultNamedOptArg, DefaultVersion=defaultNamedOptArg):
     44         ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1836, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),TableDestination
---> 45             , TableName, ReadData, DefaultVersion)
     46                 if ret is not None:
     47                         ret = Dispatch(ret, 'CreatePivotTable', '{00020872-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Comment: You should be wrapping ALL your COM lines in the `try` block, so no COM error raises in traceback but in console and you then properly release your COM objects, error or not, which should be in the `finally` block.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for the tip.  I'll follow that practice.  It's been a while and I forgot that you have destroy all your objects when you are finished with them to avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described below is what worked for me.  All of the examples I find pass a string with this format: 'Pivot Sheet!R4C1'.  I also tried 'Pivot Sheet!R4C1:R4C1' but got the same error.

For PivotCache.CreatePivotTable:
The "TableDestination" parameter needs to be a Range object:

```
pvt_rng_beg = pvt_sheet.Cells(2,2)
pvt_rng_end = pvt_sheet.Cells(2,2)
pvt_dest_rng = pvt_sheet.Range(pvt_rng_beg, pvt_rng_end)


pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=pvt_dest_rng,TableName='PivotTable1')
```

Excerpt from the C# documentation:

> **TableDestination**
>   Object
>   Required Object. The cell in the upper-left corner of the PivotTable report’s destination range (the range on the worksheet where the resulting PivotTable report will be placed). The destination range must be on a worksheet in the workbook that contains the PivotCache object specified by expression.

Here is [documentation for PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(Object, Object, Object, Object) Method in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotcache.createpivottable?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_PivotCache_CreatePivotTable_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_).  But it still does not specify the required type of the parameter objects.  I arrived at this through trial and error.

Also found the MSDN documentation for the same object and method [PivotCache.CreatePivotTable Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivotcache-createpivottable-method-excel)

Comment: You could pass range in A1 format: `TableDestination=pvt_sheet.Range("B2")`

Comment: @parfait  That works also.  The problem I appear to be having is passing the parameter as a variant.  It is not converting or casting correctly.  So I am actually creating a variant object but even that does not work.  I can however move the needle if I pass a Variant-Type (VT_ enumerator) that it does not recognize.  It throws a different error.   Example:  chrt_sheet_name_variant = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_BSTR, chrt_sheet.Name)   PivotCaches().CreatePivotChart(ChartDestination=chrt_sheet_name_variant)